# Dart- Caching config file

Tags: caching, dart, config, angular-dart

I Dart we can read some yaml config files with for example this plugin 
https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/safe_config

From what I understand, it is a file access every time.

So I was wondering, is there a clean way to cache those data ?

I could do something like on init do a Config.warmUp() to load the file but then, apart from setting a global var somewhere and then importing it but I don't think this is a "classy" move.

Is there an internal cache or buffer system included in Dart or am I obliged to do this global var stuff ?

PS : It is for an Angular App, so something like localStorage in JS (but hidden to the user would be a potential solution)

Answer (score 2):

You can always use [package:yaml](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/yaml) to load the data and then just hold on the the result of the `loadDocument` call. This will be an in-memory data structure (like a YamlMap) that you read from.

If you want to get fancy, you could use [package:json_serializable](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/json_serializable) to map the Yaml to a data object. See an example here: https://github.com/dart-lang/json_serializable/blob/master/json_serializable/test/yaml/build_config.dart